# Count the number of day if time pass a certain checkpoint in a given range of dates, e.g. number of stay in hotel

Tags: python, pandas

I would like to count the number of day if time pass a certain checkpoint in a given range of dates.  For example, the checkpoint is every midnight.  I have the check-in and check-out timestamp as follows:

```
chkin = ['2015-01-01 23:00:00',
           '2015-01-01 22:30:30',
           '2015-01-01 01:30:30',
           '2015-01-01 11:20:45']
chkout = ['2015-01-01 23:45:05',
           '2015-01-02 01:10:10',
           '2015-01-01 12:00:00',
           '2015-01-03 04:30:45']
df = pd.DataFrame({'chkin':chkin,'chkout':chkout})
```

My dataframe and the expected answer should be like this.

```
chkin                  chkout                expected answer
2015-01-01 23:00:00    2015-01-01 23:45:05   0 (because time has not yet passed the checkpoint)
2015-01-01 22:30:30    2015-01-02 01:10:10   1 (because time has passed the checkpoint for 1 time)
2015-01-01 01:30:30    2015-01-01 12:00:00   0 (because time has not yet passed the checkpoint)
2015-01-01 11:20:45    2015-01-02 04:30:45   2 (because time has passed the checkpoint for 2 times)
```

I was trying to get the answer using the following command but not success yet.

```
df['answer'] = (df['chkout'] - df['chkin']).dt.days
```

May i have your suggestions?  Thank you in advance.

Comment: You are almost there, it would be df['answer'] = df['chkout'].dt.day - df['chkin'].dt.day

Comment: omg ... thanks a lot Vaishali

Comment: Your last example is wrong. 11 am to 04 am of the next da is 1

Comment: Also your answers will be more accurate for what you want if you don’t include the hours minutes and seconds.

Answer (score 0):

You can subtract datetime objects like this:

```
import datetime
format = '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'
difference = abs((datetime.datetime.strptime(df['chkout'], format) - datetime.datetime.strptime(df['chkin'], format)).days)
print(difference)
```

Although, you will get more accurate answers if you don’t include the hours minutes and seconds, e.g: running your first example check out and check in times through the above code produces 1 instead of 0. You can fix this by just using the days and not the hours like so:

```
from datetime import datetime as dt
format = '%Y-%m-%d'
difference = abs((dt.strptime(df['chkout'].split(' ')[0], format) - dt.strptime(df['chkin'].split(' ')[0], format)).days)
print(difference)
```